# Identifying .NET runtime hosts

Tags: .net

I am not a programmer by any stretch of the imagination and do not have a firm grasp on how .NET applications work, however, I am required to document the .Net runtime host that invokes each application on our system.

All applications we have are .Net 4. I have found a handful of sites that describe ways to determine what .DLLs are being run by a program (tasklist /M | find "YourAppName") and that tasklist /m "mscor*" will list .Net applications using mscoree.dll (which all of our .Net programs appear to be using and I believe is the standard .Net runtime) but I don't know if the .DLLs listed are every .DLL that application will use and which are considered runtime hosts. I have read about the Common Runtime Language and that it is a .NET run-time environment, but I don't believe it is a runtime host.

I contacted the software developer and they stated "it is a fair assumption to make that the application can load all Dlls located in the application folder and subfolders, in addition to those of the .NET Framework." but that doesn't seem very helpful unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I might be doing the same documentation you are and if the .NET application is a Command Line, Windows Service or WinForms app then the runtime host is Windows Shell.  If it is an ASP.NET Application then IIS is the runtime host.

HTH,
Richard

Comment: Thank you for answering, I eventually figured it out but failed to update this post. To collect additional information utilize Sysinternals Process Explorer. It is a great tool for evaluating .NET apps as it will allow you to view which .NET assemblies and App Domains your programs are using.